# How to configure "multiple" prop in Vuetify v-combobox component for single selection

Tags: javascript, combobox, vuejs2, vuetify.js

In a large Vue app using Vuetify, I have the following re-usable component used throughout the app:

```
<template>
  <v-combobox
    v-model="input"
    :items="available"
    :item-value="itemValue"
    :item-text="itemText"
    :label="label"
    :disabled="disabled"
    :hint="hint"
    chips
    multiple
    persistent-hint
    @input="myInput"
  >
    <template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
      <v-chip
        :close="!disabled"
        @input="remove(data.item)"
      >
        <strong>{{ data.item.code }}</strong>
      </v-chip>
    </template>
  </v-combobox>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'BaseSelectChip',
  props: {
    hint: String,
    value: Array,
    label: String,
    available: Array,
    disabled: Boolean,
    itemText: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    itemValue: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    input: {
      get() {
        return this.value;
      },
      set(val) {
        this.$emit('input', val);
      },
    },
  },
  methods: {
    myInput(items) {
      this.input = [...this.items];
      this.$emit('input', items);
    },
    remove(item) {
      const newItems = this.input.slice();
      newItems.splice(this.input.indexOf(item), 1);
      this.$emit('input', newItems);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

and it is typically used like so:

```
<BaseSelectChip
  label="Liveness Options"
  :value="tenantBiometricLiveness"
  :available="getAvailableLiveness"
  :disabled="!hasBiometric"
  itemValue="code"
  itemText="name"
  :hint="livenessHint"
  @input="livenessUpdated"
/>
```

To this point, all of the implementations in my app have allowed multiple selections, but I have a case where I want to limit it to a single selection. Per the [docs](https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox), it is a a boolean, but also says that this prop `Accepts array for value`. In addition, it states that the default value is `false`, but when it is passed by itself to `v-combobox`, it allows for multiple options to be selected. If I define a prop in `BaseSelectChip` like so:

```
props: {
  multiple: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
  },
}
```

and then pass it to `v-combobox`

```
  <v-combobox
    v-model="input"
    :items="available"
    :item-value="itemValue"
    :item-text="itemText"
    :label="label"
    :disabled="disabled"
    :hint="hint"
    chips
    :multiple="multiple"
    persistent-hint
    @input="myInput"
  >
```

no matter how I pass it from the parent component, my screen is just blank, and I get no console warnings, which tells me Veutify is dying silently somewhere.

When I remove `multiple` from the `v-combobox` element, I get a blank item in my field, even though there is no item in the field (the `items` prop):
[image: blank chip in v-combobox]

In addition, if there is valid value passed to the field, removing the `multiple` prop caused the data value to not be shown for some reason (the same result as when there is no data, as shown above).

So my questions are these:
1) How do I pass the value for the `multiple` prop to `<BaseSelectChip>` (and subsequently to `v-combobox`) as needed by `v-combobox`?
2) How can I configure the combobox to only allow one item to be selected at time, and only show a chip when an item is actually selected?

**UPDATE:** So to implement @skirtle's suggestion below: I modified `BaseSelectChip` like so:

```
  <v-combobox
    v-model="input"
    :items="available"
    :item-value="itemValue"
    :item-text="itemText"
    :label="label"
    :disabled="disabled"
    chips
    :multiple="multiple"
    @input="myInput"
  >

...

props: {
  multiple: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
      default: true,
    },
  },
```

and then added `:multiple="false"` in the parent component. That seems to work fine, but there's now one side effect: in `BaseSelectChip`, the value that is emitted from `myInput` (coming from the `@input` event on the combobox) is an `Observer` instead of an `Array`. This causes problems in the parent component, because it's looking for an array. Why is it using an Observer?

Comment: You seem to have called the prop `multiple` but you're passing it to `v-combobox` as `multipleItems`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's a typo. I actually tried it multiple ways to see if the name of what I passed it made a difference (it didn't).

Comment: You should just need to pass `:multiple="false"` in the template that creates `BaseSelectChip`. That should get you equivalent behaviour to omitting the `multiple` attribute on `v-combobox`. But that's just the start, you've got several lines of code that assume the `value` will be an array. The docs line *'Accepts array for value'* is a little confusing but it means that when `multiple` is `true` the `value` (bound with `v-model`) will be an array. If `multiple` is `false` then the `value` will no longer be an array.

Comment: Great, could you do me a favor and add that as an answer so I can respond? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any prop that has a `type` of `Boolean` can be written using a shorthand to pass `true`. So when you write:

```html
<v-combobox multiple>
```

That is just a shorthand for:

```html
<v-combobox :multiple="true">
```

This is not specific to Vuetify, it is general Vue behaviour and applies to all components.

In your case you have set the default to `true`, so you will need to explicitly pass `false`:

```html
<BaseSelectChip
  :multiple="false"
>
```

Be careful to include the `:` at the front or it'll pass the string `'false'` instead, which is very different.

You mentioned an entry in the docs that said:

> Accepts array for value

What this means is that if you set `multiple` to `true` then the `value` prop of `v-combobox` will need to be an array. In your code you aren't setting the prop `value` directly but you are setting it via `v-model`.

If `multiple` is set to `false` then `value` will not be expecting an array. As you're using `v-model` this will affect you in both directions. You have a few lines that seems to assume the value will be an array, so they will need changing.

This is probably why you're seeing a single, empty chip. I'm guessing that you're passing in an empty array. But with `multiple` set to `false` it'll just treat that array as the selected value. There's no special handling of arrays in that case, it's just a value like any other. It'll be looking for `[].code` and `[].name` for the `item-value` and `item-text`, which will be `undefined`.

Comment: Boolean prop behavior isn't specific to Vue, it's general HTML attribute behavior. The existence of a boolean attribute indicates a truthy value.